# Is it possible to turn off lighting effects?

Tags: kml

I have a 3D data visualized as a ground layer and two vertical curtains:

http://webapps.datafed.net/Datasets/curtain_demo.kmz

The north-south curtain across west states is dark on the east side, brighter on the west. This is data visualization, I'd like it to use just the same color rendering as GE does on the map. Is there a way to turn off these lighting effects?

This does not look good on the Mac. I have submitted a bug about it:

http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=966